# Спавн актора (оружия) при передачи АкторКласса из переменной

Tags: unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine

**Старая простая логика:** Есть BP_оружие и в чартере нода спавна актора, где АкторКласс выбирается из списка, далее (после спавна) записывается в переменную и из этой переменной спокойно достаются все функции и прочее. Всё рабоатет как автомат АК.

**Новая логика аля инвентарь:** Итем(актор) хранит в себе переменную с АкторКлассом моего BP_оружие. Логика почти таже, я достаю эту переменную (тот же сраный актор класс как при выборе из списка) и передаю в ноду спавн актора. Но следущая переменная, в которую я записал заспавненый Актор не работает, ноды из нее не достаются которые в оригинале, мол несовместимы.

И как мне решить эту проблему, я не могу сделать логику оружия в самом оружие (не в главном акторе, не в акторе итема, всё не работает).

*Вижу костыльную тему с проверкой в персонаже, что за итем и исходя из этого подбирать ноду с актором из списка, а не из переменной. Но как это будет по оптимизации, если у меня будет очень много оружия...*

Первый раз пишу тему по анрилу и не знаю как лучше поделиться кодом, буду рад помощи, спасибо.

Comment: По скрипту. Это всё дело происходит в функции в персонаже. В функции также не работает старая логика.
Но если делать в ЭвентГрафе, то всё нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, сделав все функции оружия в чартере, а в итемах передавал переменные для них. Но всё равно не понимаю почему спавн актор в функции себя так ведет. Спасибо анрил за головную боль